# Is it possible to take screenshots while screen is off?

Tags: python, windows, screen, screenshot

I'm writing a python app to detect visual changes in a browser window. I've managed to get it working well by using the mss python module to take screenshots but it only seems to work while my screen is on. After my monitor sleeps from inactivity, the screenshots produced by mss are all identical to the last screenshot taken prior to the monitors going to sleep.

I've tried using the approaches detailed in these answers:

[Python - Screenshot of background/inactive window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53551676/python-screenshot-of-background-inactive-window)

[How to take a screenshot from part of screen with mss python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71453766/how-to-take-a-screenshot-from-part-of-screen-with-mss-python)

But they both produce the same cached screenshots while the screen is off. Is it possible to keep taking screenshots while the monitor is asleep?

Comment: Do the results differ if you turn your monitor off directly? As in comparison to "screen saver" mode, so to say? Edit: Also, does it make a difference if your monitor goes to sleep from some device option or your system goes to display power saving mode?

Comment: why don't you prevent the screen from going to sleep ?

Comment: @AchilleG That is absolutely a solution to the problem, but I would prefer the option to let them sleep for power consumption purposes.

Comment: @JanS Good Question! Interestingly it works if I just turn off the display the window is on. It also works if I turn off all my displays. It is the windows-controlled monitor sleeping that seems to be the issue.

Comment: Then maybe letting the monitor go to sleep itself (if it has the option) instead of using the system screen saver/power saving mode might be a solution.